# Como detectar a maior palavra de uma string em C?

Tags: c, string, lógica

Me deparei com este problema durante um projeto pessoal, é mais curiosidade mesmo, queria por favor, pedir para quem puder me dar uma luz com isso, pois já resolvi o problema em outras linguagens apenas em C que ainda não.

Como eu posso fazer para detectar a maior palavra de uma string, no caso de uma frase digitada pelo usuario? Estou com dificuldade justo na parte quando detecto o primeiro espaço em branco, dentro do 'If' dentro do laço 'for' .

```
for(i = 0; str[i] < MAX; i++){
        if(str[i] == ' '){ //CONTINUAR a string depois do primeiro espaço;
            strcpy(maior, str); //Copia palavra em maior
            strcpy(temp, str);
        }
```

- Bem aqui, eu não consigo continuar, nao sei como continuar comparando e ele sempre me devolve a ultima palavra da frase, nunca a maior. Já tentei montar funções proprias para quando detectar o primeiro espaço, ele valida a string até aquele ponto e copia para uma outra string de char, mas nao deu em nada.

Se alguém tiver uma solução, só consegui resolver isso com a função em JAVA que chama Split que fragmenta a string em um vetor sendo cada indice uma palavra, ai fica mais fácil de comparar. Não imagino se pode ser feito algo parecido em C. Mais para sanar essa curiosidade minha que venho aqui. Agradeço quem tiver um tempo, obrigado e abraço!

Answer (score 0):

A ideia dessa função abaixo é armazenar em um temporário onde a palavra começa e qual o seu comprimento. Depois ela verifica se o o temporário é maior do que a maior palavra encontrada até o momento e caso for, esta se torna a nova maior palavra.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    char palavra[200];
    printf("Insira uma palavra: ");
    //scanf("%s", palavra);
    strcpy(palavra, "Como eu detectar a maior palavra de uma string");
    int tamanho = strlen(palavra);

    int maior=0, ini=0; //variaveis da maior palavra
    int cont=0, temp_ini=0; //variaveis do temporario
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <=tamanho; i++){
        //se a frase terminou ou a palavra terminou
        if(i==tamanho || palavra[i] == ' '){
            if(maior<cont){
                maior=cont;
                ini=temp_ini;
            }
            cont=0;
            temp_ini=i+1;
        }
        else{
            cont++;
        }
    }

    printf("\nMaior palavra: ", ini);
    for (i = ini; i <ini+maior; i++)
        printf("%c", palavra[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A função abaixo recebe uma string por parametro e retorna a maior palavra contida nessa String. Ela verifica o tamanho da maior palavra e a coloca num temporário retornando no final a maior palavra.

```
char* maior_string(char *s){
    int temp = 0, fim = 0; 
    char *maior = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(s));
    if(!maior)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    strcpy(maior, "\0");
    while(*s){
        if(*s == ' '){
            if(fim > temp){
                strncpy(maior, s - fim, fim);
                temp = fim;
            }
            fim = 0;
        } else 
            fim++;
        s++;
    }
    if(fim > temp){
        strncpy(maior, s - fim, fim);
        temp = fim;
    }
    return maior;
}
```