# Return na função recursiva não está funcionando

Tags: c, recursão

Eu tava resolvendo uma questão:

Escreva um programa que ler várias palavras de um usuário e exibe qual foi a
maior palavra digitada. O programa deve parar de ler palavras quando o usuário
entrar com a palavra “fim”.
Exemplo:

**- Input:**

- Digite uma palavra: gato
- Digite uma palavra: cachorro
- Digite uma palavra: peixe
- Digite uma palavra: coelho
- Digite uma palavra: fim

**- Output:**

- A maior palavra é: cachorro

Aí fiz um código usando recursividade, segue o código:

'''

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <string.h>

        char *maior_palavra(char *str, int n)
        {
            int ch, i = 0;
            char palavra[61];

            printf("Digite uma palavra: ");
            while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n'){

                palavra[i] = ch;
                i++;

                if(strcmp(palavra, "fim") == 0){
                    break;
                }

            }

            palavra[i] = '\0';

            if (strcmp(palavra, "fim") != 0){
                if(strlen(palavra) > strlen(str)){
                    strcpy(str, palavra);
                    maior_palavra(str, n);
                }

                if(strlen(palavra) < strlen(str)){
                    maior_palavra(str, n);
                }

            }

            if(strcmp(palavra, "fim") == 0){
                return str;
            }

        }
        int main()
        {
            char nome[61] = {0};
            maior_palavra(nome, 61);
            printf("A maior palavra eh: %s", nome);
            return 0;
        }
```

'''

Mas, ao chegar no **return str**, o código não sai da função, acontecendo outra repetição da função.

Comment: E por que fez recursivo? A menos que seja exigência do exercício, não há motivo nenhum pra isso, e certamente não é o melhor jeito de fazer... Exemplo de uma solução um pouco melhor: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203261/112052

Answer (score 0, accepted):

na linguagem c não se pode retornar vetor , e uma string na linguagem  é um vetor de char , e com um finalizador de string **'\0'** ,  assim depois de inserir um caractere na palavra coloque esse finalizador , para fazer a comparação , senão erros, e seu código poderia ser assim  :

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* maior_palavra(char* str, int n)      //  str eh iGual nome q estah na funcao main
{                                          //  assim str e nome ocupam a mesma posicao 
                                           //  na memoria
    int ch, i = 0;                         
    char palavra[61] = {} ;                //  para evitar warnning's do compilador 
                                           //  melhor iniciaLizar as variaveiS
    printf("Digite uma palavra: ");
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') 
    {

        palavra[i] = ch;
        i++;
        palavra[i] = '\0';                 //  finaliza a string
        if (strcmp(palavra, "fim") == 0)   //  para poDer comparar
        {
            return str;                    //  AQui nao vai retornar naDa , pois na Linguagem C 
                                           //  nao se pode retornar vetor , mas apenaS 
                                           //  numeros  e/ou uma struct
        }

    }
    if (strlen(palavra) >= strlen(str)) 
    {
        strcpy(str, palavra);
        maior_palavra(str, n);
    }
    else
        maior_palavra(str, n);
}
int main()
{
    char nome[61] = { 0 };
    maior_palavra(&nome[0], 61);           //  os colchetes com zero dentro significa que enviou a 
                                           //  posição inicial do vetor de char nome , ou "string" para a funcao 
    printf("\n\nA maior palavra eh: %18s\n\n\n", nome);
    return 0;
}
```